# cordova angularjs routing not working

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-routing, angular-routing

I have an app created by cordova. So I use also angularjs. My problem is routing via angularjs $routeProvider works on Chrome Browser but not on my phone.

```
var app = angular.module('appGenerator', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    if (isMobile.Android() == true){
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }else{
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }

    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: "pages/tablePage.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
        })
        .when('/Contacts', {
            templateUrl: "pages/contacts.html",
            controller: "ContactsCtrl"
        }).otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
}]);
```

[image]

Can't understand why it didn't works on my smartphone if I tested it there. On Browser it works..

**Update 1:** 
When I call an alert on my ContactsCtrl controller. It appears. But then I got an net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///contacts).

Answer (score 0):

What is the error exactly? Is it not finding the route provider itself? Some of the things to make sure of when writing cordova apps.

1. Make sure all your content is in the www folder (js files, css and images. Everything)
2. Make sure that you reference paths to files with the 'www/' infornt.

I usually set up a local site that has the exact same directory structure of my cordova application. This way it's easy to debug problems that might occur without having to run in on the device. It's a good way to sort out things like path errors early on.

Comment: Yes I think so. It doesn't find the route provider itself. Just calling /Contacts and this didn't work instead of calling the provider and get the templateUrl. Are u sure, I have to reference the paths with www/ ? like www/partials/contacts,html ?

Comment: @ErdemGüngör For all the cordova applications I have made. Yes I had to do that all the time.

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: @ErdemGüngör Can you set up a website a with the same structure on your pc so you can debug it better? Then you can see where the file is being requested from. Use IIS to create a website with the same structure. That's the way I usually solve stuff like this.

Comment: If I run the app on my Chrome Browser, it works normally. Everthing is okay. Not on my phone.. Never worked with IIS

Comment: @ErdemGüngör Are you saying that you're running your cordova app using angular in Chrome?Or are you just running your angular app as is in chrome. Because that will work fine.Running it in cordova you will need to change all your file paths to point to www/ . Literally all of them. I did what you are asking about, and I got it working. Dealt with the same problems. But setting up a localhosted website with the cordova app (not the stand-alone angular app) was how I figured out all the requests are going to places where the files were not found. Sorry I can't help you more dude. Hope you fix it

Comment: I'm testing it on Chrome also on my phone. It's a cordova app with angularjs. So add www/partials/tablePage.html to the templateUrl ? Or where should i change it too?

Comment: So the angular app you're running on chrome is hosted in the www folder with the following in the root directory? css(dir). img(dir). js(dir). codrova.js(file). cordova_plugins.js(file). index.html(file) ... If that's the structure of the app you're running in your chrome browser could you please post an image of the network tab in chrome dev tools. if nothing in there has www/ infront of it. Then you are NOT running the app with the SAME SETUP as cordova on your machine. I have a strong sense that the app you're running on your chrome is a pure angular app, not hosted in www.

Comment: And also not loading through cordova xhrHelper and so on.

Comment: Hey buddy. thanks for your help. But it was a problem with my script tags.. loaded this file "js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" before of angular files and bootstrap  gaves me the error. after i delete this tag, the error was gone... 3 -4 horror days...